# compiling gstreamer-plugins-bad 1.6.4 with Qt

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I have Qt 5.6.1 installed on my ARM based Linux system. The PATH variables and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables contain the path to the relevant QT directories as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib:/usr/local/Qt-5.6.1/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:/usr/local/Qt-5.6.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Now, I would like to compile gstreamer-plugins-bad 1.6.4 from sources and when I run the configuration script, it never configures it with Qt. The message is:

```
configure: *** checking feature: Qt elements ***
configure: *** for plug-ins: qt ***
checking for QT... no
configure: *** These plugins will not be built: qt
```

I tried calling the configure script with --enable-qt but to no avail as well. I also copied the pkg-config files found in `/usr/local/Qt-5.6.1/lib/pkgconfig` to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` but again to no avail.

How may I enable qt support in the plugins?

Comment: So this is the [check](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/configure.ac#n2860) .. it uses pkg config as you probably noticed.. have you tried running `pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt5Core` ?

Comment: @otopolsky Thanks! That did the trick.

Comment: you may answer your own question then :)